# How do I bind each child of one element to the child of another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

There is a bootstrap carousel that is changing automatically:

```
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="active"> </div>
  <div class="">       </div>
  <div class="">       </div>
  <div class="">       </div>
</div>
```

Only one div is set to active at a time, and it cycles through like that.
How can I bind all of carousel's children to another element so that it can set it's specific child to be active as well.

For example:

```
<div id="copy-cat">
  <li class=""> </li>
  <li class=""> </li>
  <li class=""> </li>
  <li class=""> </li>
</div>

<div id="carousel">
  <div class="active"> </div>
  <div class="">       </div>
  <div class="">       </div>
  <div class="">       </div>
</div>
```

How can I bind copy-cat to have the same child active as carousel?  Keep in mind, I don't want to copy all of the class attributes- just detect that one is active, and set that same numbered child to active also.

Comment: Does copy-cat have to have the same number of children as carousel? Also, in your example you mix `<li>` and `<div>` tags between them, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes. <li> and <div> is how it is.  They will have the same number of children.

Comment: Please provide a JSFIDDLE. BTW, who changes `active` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Bootstrap's `slid` event callback:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/6xF7k/

```
$('#carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    // get the index of the currently active panel
    var myIndex = $(this).find('div.active').index();

    // set the element with that index active, deactivating the others
    $('#copy-cat').find('li').removeClass('active').eq(myIndex)
        .addClass('active');
})
```

Notice that I changed `#copy-cat` to `ul` to make it valid HTML.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap carousel has some events that you can tap into.

Information about the events can be found in the "Events" section under the [Carousel documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

I would recommend doing something like:

```
<div id="copy-cat">
    <div id="copy-1" class="active"></div>
    <div id="copy-2" class=""></div>
    <div id="copy-3" class=""></div>
    <div id="copy-4" class=""></div>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" data-transition-to="#copy-1">
            <p>something1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-transition-to="#copy-2">
            <p>something2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-transition-to="#copy-3">
            <p>something3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-transition-to="#copy-4">
            <p>something4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add a listener as described in the event section, and inspect the `relatedTarget`.

Use the `data-transition-to` to figure out the class to add the `active` class to.

Javascript to support this approach:

```
$('#carousel').carousel({
    interval:false //or whatever options you want
});

$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel',function (event) {
    $('#copy-cat .active').removeClass('active');
    $(event.relatedTarget.dataset.transitionTo).addClass('active');
});

$('#carousel').carousel('next');
```

This is is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SU5gf/) ...I disabled transitioning & you will have to inspect the DOM to see that the copy-cat div is being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Given an element `x`, you can get the index of `x` in its parent's `.children()` by calling `x.index()`.  In your example, `$("div.active").index()` would return 0, the div following would return 1, etc.  So you should be able to do something like the following:

```
$("#copy-cat :nth-child("+(1+$("#carousel div.active").index()) + ")").addClass("active");
```

(`nth-child` is 1-index-based, so you need to add 1.  You could also call `eq()`, which is 0-based.)

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/tn5NV/) for a rough example.

But this is only a general answer.  If there are Bootstrap methods for this purpose, by all means use them.